# The transaction is still 0confirmation

Tags: bitcoin-cash

When is the miner checking the first transaction?
Why is not it confirmed?

network: testnet
tx: 6d1410de07627e8effdee58625be3c32962bfa7baec69a92ec12c125ed58e9e3

https://www.blocktrail.com/tBCC/tx/6d1410de07627e8effdee58625be3c32962bfa7baec69a92ec12c125ed58e9e3

Comment: More than 1 day passed. Who knows the cause?

Comment: Yes, the BCH testnet has miners unwilling to accept others' transactions.

Comment: > JBaczuk 58  
  Thank you, I will check that question

Comment: > MCCCS
Thank you very much
Why do not you want to accept other's transactions?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, there are no usable mining rewards in the testnet because testnet coins are worthless.

To test transactions you may need to mine your own blocks.